# How to show both date and time in datepicker in php

Tags: php, html, datetimepicker

I have following script to get the date in PHP.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
           });
           $(function(){
                $("#from_date").datepicker();
                $("#to_date").datepicker();
           });
           $('#filter').click(function(){
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')
                {
                     $.ajax({
                          url:"fetch2.php",
                          method:"POST",
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
                          success:function(data)
                          {
                               $('#order_table').html(data);
                          }
                     });
                }
                else
                {
                     alert("Please Select Date");
                }
           });
      });
 </script>
```

Following themes are used to get the widget.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Input type is set to text in datetimepicker.

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />
        </div>
```

This works fine, and I could get the date, But I need to get both date and time. How should I get?

I tried by replacing `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd hh:ii'` as well in datepicker script. But it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: This uses moment.js format specifiers, does it not?  `ii` is not even on the list, https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: @CBroe then what should I replace?